# Find the order of the conjugacy class of $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone please verify my answer? Note: This is not homework, only self study.

> Find the order of the conjugacy class of $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$

We proceed by first finding the order of the stabilizer of the given matrix. Then, we can use the fact that $|O(x)||Stab(x)| = |G|$. Note that
$$\frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ad - 2bc & ab \\ -cd & -bc+2ad \end{bmatrix}$$

So, if the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ stabilizes $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$, then we must have $b = 0, c=0$, and $a$ and $d$ can be arbitrary as long as neither equals zero. Hence, $|Stab(A)| = 16$. Note that $|GL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)| = 24 \times 20$. So, $|O(x)| = \frac{20 \times 24}{16} = 30$

So, there are $30$ elements in the conjugacy class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks right.

Another way to get the same result would be that a matrix is a conjugate of $A$ exactly if it has $1$ and $2$ as its eigenvalues, and each of those needs an 1D eigenspace. So to make such a matrix we need to choose one 1D subspace of $\mathbb F_5^2$ to be the eigenspace of eigenvalue $1$ (and there are $24/4=6$ different subspaces to choose from), and then those one of the remaining $5$ subspaces to be the eigenspace with eigenvalue $2$.