# how to find the order of an orbit of a matrix with entries interpreted in $GL_2(\mathbb F_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, orbit-equivalence

My question is from Artin's algebra:
Interpreting the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\                
                                         0 & 2
                         \end{bmatrix}$
in $GL_2(\mathbb F_5)$, find the order of the orbit.

I'm not sure where to start, if I describe the orbit of this matrix normally, wouldn't it be all $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} p & 0\\                
                                                       0 & q
                                        \end{bmatrix}$ with $p,q \in \mathbb R$?
Would it be the same if the entries were interpreted in $\mathbb F_5$ as well?

Comment: Can you cite more specifically? Problem and page number?

Comment: @coiso yeah, it's problem 7.10 part b), pg 191.

Comment: So the task is to find the size of the orbit of that matrix when $GL$ acts by conjugation. The elements of the orbit needn't be diagonal. Have you tried conjugating the matrix by other matrices yet? Anyway, the sidebar gave out this dupe as a related link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404497/find-the-order-of-the-conjugacy-class-of-a-beginbmatrix-1-0-0-2-en?rq=1

Comment: oh i see thanks, do you know if conjugacy class means the same as orbit? I think it does if I'm understanding the term right but just to be sure...

Comment: A conjugacy class is the orbit of a group element under the action of conjugation. Other kinds of orbits are not called conjugacy classes.